# Is it possible to find $\angle BOA$?

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$ , $\angle BAC=80^o$ . suppose $O$ is a point in triangle $ABC$ that $OBC=30^\circ$ and $OCB=10^\circ$ . Is it possible to find $\angle BOA$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where do you get stuck?
Hint: The triangle is isoceles, and $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter The triangle doesn't have to be isosceles. See the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because this only fixes the $OBC$ triangle upto congruency.

In other words, for any $ABC$ with $BAC=80$ (and variable $ABC$ and $ACB$), you can find the point $O$.

Here's what I mean -

**Triangle 1**
[image]

**Triangle 2**

[image]

Comment: Though the point $O$ doesn't have to be inside the triangle. E.g., when $\angle ABC<30^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 3):

No, because take such a triangle $ABC$ with $O$ fixed and consider the circumcircle of $ABC$. Then you can move the point $A$ along the circle without changing $\angle OBC$,$\angle OCB$ and $\angle BAC$, but surely $\angle BOA$ will change.

Comment: nice................+1